# How to find elements by class name length

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, build-automation

I'm looking for every class in the page having a certain length.

Now I'm using

```
list=[] #empty array
elements = x.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@class]") #finds out every element that have a class in the page, x is my chromedriver
for element in elements: #inspect every single element found
    class = element.get_attribute('class') #filters only the class name
    if (len(class)==8): #filters the class name exacy length
        list.append(element) #the element is now inside of the list and the loop can inspect next element
```

But this is VERY slow, I think it's because of the for loop. Have you got any idea on how to look for a specific length directly inside of the find_elements function or avoiding the for loop or any other solution to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried logging the length of the `elements` list? how big is it?

Comment: 9-10 elements with the right length, gomna try to find out the find elements list lenght tomorrow

Comment: The total of the first find_elements is 700-800 entries depending on the page and the process takes nearly 30 seconds to find all 9-10 classes i am looking for

Comment: Can't you just use a regex on the whole HTML code? This would then find your classes, afterwhich you can do a specific search using selenium.

Comment: Never heard about it, can you explain how it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm just answering my own question because i think i found a very fast method to do it

i wanted to find classname "g" or "g <6alphanumerics>"
for some reason in javascript if you make document.getElementsByClassName('g') it finds everything i needed

So the new snippet is:

```
classes = x.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('g')")
```

the return is important otherwise the array will be empty